# Controller and view association and self.method still confuses me

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay so in the index portion of my controller I set

```
@patients = Patient.all
```

then in patients_helper.rb

```
def race_abrev
 return self.caucasian
end
```

where caucasian is an integer datatype column in the patients table

then in the view index.html.erb

```
<% @patients.each do |p| %>
  <td><%= p.gender %></td>
  <td><%= p.ethnicity %></td>
  <td><%= p.race_abrev %></td>
<% end %>
```

I get a

```
undefined method `race_abrev' for #<Patient:0xb4d95cd8>
```

I've checked the table and I'm expecting patient.caucasian to return the integer 1, what am I missing..any insight to a fundamental misunderstanding I seem to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`race_abrev` is a helper, not a method on `Patient`:

```
<%= race_abrev(p) %>
```

And the helper itself would return `p.caucasian`, although it'd seem like you'd actually want to *do* something with the value of `caucasian`, like a compare or something.

All this said, I'm not sure why you're not defining it (or what "it" actually is) on the model, since so far it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the view, which is what view helpers are for.

If you're storing something in the DB you want to transform it may or may not belong in a view helper; if it's to turn it into something human-readable I'd be more likely to put it in the model.

Comment: I've got some check boxes that return either 1 or 0.  I wanted to add up the check boxes and in this case return how many races were selected. Your solution works great, thanks!